# Angular 5 passing object to a component

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

So i have created the following class:

```
export class PresentObject {
    public type: string;
    public resourceUrl: string;
    public text: string;

}
```

And the following component:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {PresentObject} from '../classes/present-object';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-video',
    templateUrl: './video.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./video.component.css']
})
export class VideoComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input()
    view: PresentObject;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.view.text);
    }

}
```

Now I attempt to insert that through HTML:

```
  <section *ngFor="let view of views; let last = last" [ngSwitch]="view.type">
    <app-video *ngSwitchCase="'video'" view="{{view}}"></app-video>
  <span *ngIf="last">{{repeatComplete()}}</span>
</section>
```

After debugging I can see if I `console.log(this.view)` i get: `"[object Object]"`

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: i think you dont need {{ }}, try this [view]="view"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <section *ngFor="let view of views; let last = last" [ngSwitch]="view.type">
    <app-video *ngSwitchCase="'video'" view="view"></app-video>
  <span *ngIf="last" (click)="repeatComplete()">LAST</span>
</section>
```